# Critical value for the separation of two normal distributions.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, roots

Consider the equation:

$$x \mathrm{e}^{\frac1{2} ((x-z)^2 - x^2)} + y(x - z) = 0$$

And limiting $z > 0$ and $y \ge 1$, for what values of $z$ and $y$ does the function in $x$ have exactly 2 real solutions?  Looking for a function $z(y)$, but I can work with any implicit closed form or even approximate solution, as I've spent some time playing around with it, and I do not believe that there is an explicit closed form solution to this problem.

Motivation: Consider two normally distributed random variables $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $\mathcal{N}(z, 1)$ which are drawn from with probabilities $\frac{1}{y+1}$ and $\frac{y}{y+1}$.  The function $z(y)$ are the $z$ are exactly the critical value for the separation of the two modes.  For values of $z$ less than $z(y)$ there are not two separate modes, for values greater than this there are.

A few known values of this function are $z(1) = 2$, and $z(2) \approx 2.627509131962$.

Comment: Why exactly $2$ real solutions rather than changing from $1$ to $3$?

Comment: The number of real solutions changes from 1 to 3.  With 1 they are not separated, with 3 they are.  But with 2, which occurs for only one value where the second root is a double root, is the critical value.

Comment: When $y=1$ and $z=2$, I would have thought the only real root was at $x=1$ (perhaps as a triple root) while with $y=1$ and $z=2.0001$ there are three real roots near $0.98273, 1.00005, 1.01737$: two local maxima surrounding one local minimum.  But playing further, I think you get may only be able to get exactly $2$ real roots when $y \not=1$.

Comment: That's true.  If that's the case then we can simply defined z(1) = 2 for the degenerate case.  Or however you prefer, it will be the same function either way.

Comment: I have set up a [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tmsp8ifffq) to aid in getting a feel for this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @OmnipotentEntity’s answer, let $x_0^2=e^w\implies z=\frac1{x_0}+x_0=2\cosh(\frac w2)$

$$y=x_0^2\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_0^2}-x_0^2\right)\right)=e^{\sinh(w)-w}$$

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816307/isolating-x-analytically-in-this-equation-xeaxx-fy/4732155#4732155) inverts $\sinh(x)+ax$ via an [inverse Laplace transform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseLaplaceTransform.html); define its inverse as $f_a(x)$. Thus, $z(y)=2\cosh(\frac12f_{-1}(\ln(y))$:

$$\boxed{y(z) = \frac{\sqrt{z^4-4 z^2+2 \sqrt{z^2-4} z-\sqrt{z^2-4} z^3+2}}{ \sqrt{2 e^{-z \sqrt{z^2-4}}}}\implies z(y)=2\cos\left(\frac14\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{y^s}s\operatorname A_{-s}(s)ds\right)}$$

shown here:
[image]

is $z(2)$ which matches the question. $\operatorname A_v(z)$ is the [associated Anger Weber function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10). Perhaps this explicit expression will help.

Comment: Maybe one can find an integral only representation

Answer (score 1):

If we let $f(x) = x \mathrm{e}^{\frac1{2} ((x-z)^2 - x^2)} + y(x - z)$ then at our critical points we know that $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f'(x_0) = 0$.  We can consider this a system of two simultaneous equations and solve for $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x_0$, then eliminate $x_0$ to find $y(z)$.  However, this function is not invertible.

We have:

$$
  z = \frac1{x_0} + x_0
$$
$$
  y = y=x_0^2\exp\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_0^2}-x_0^2\right)
$$

We can express $y(z)$ as

$$
  y(z) = \frac{\sqrt{z^4-4 z^2+2 \sqrt{z^2-4} z-\sqrt{z^2-4} z^3+2}}{ \sqrt{2 e^{-z \sqrt{z^2-4}}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is as follows. Conceptually, I think it is pretty much what you have shown in your solution. I just feel this is a bit more intepretable. Let $f(x) := x\exp\left(\frac{1}{2} ((x-z)^2 - x^2))\right)$ and $g(x) = -y(x - z)$. What you are essentially searching for is that the equation $f(x) = g(x)$ has exactly two 2 real solutions.

Given $g(x)$ is a line, the only way the above relation can hold (for the given $f(x)$) is when this said line is a tangent to $f(x)$ and it cuts it again exactly once more at another point. Furthermore, it has to be a tangent at a point $x > 1/z$. This follows from the fact that $f(x)$ is increasing for $x \leq 1/z$ and any tangent will cut it exactly once. In fact, this will give you the region for exactly one solution. Let $x_0 > 1/z$ and the tangent at $x_0$ is given as $f'(x_0) x + (f(x_0) - x_0 f'(x_0))$. You want this to be the same as $g(x)$. On comparing the equations, we obtain,
\begin{align*}
y & = -f'(x_0) \\
yz & = f(x_0) - x_0 f'(x_0).
\end{align*}
This implies $x_0$ satisfies the following relation,
\begin{align*}
f'(x_0)(x_0 - z) & = f(x_0) \\
\implies \exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2} - zx_0\right)(1 - x_0z)(x_0 - z) & = x_0\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2} - zx_0\right) \\
\implies x_0^2 - x_0 z + 1 = 0.
\end{align*}

On solving this, we obtain, $x_0 = \frac{1}{2}\left(z - \sqrt{z^2 - 4}\right)$ (assuming $z \geq 2$). We choose this root since $x_0 > 1/z$.

The required value of $y = -f'(x_0)$ for the above value (which I think matches what you obtained). The condition $z \geq 2$ is a consequence of $y \geq 1$, implying that this solution covers the entire range.